# Web GIS mapping for Beginner

Tags: python, vb.net, web, gis, arcgis

I am new to Web GIS mapping, I am interested to learn about WEB GIS and what are the skills needed.

I Know Arcgis Desktop, FME, VBA, Microstation and Autocad.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are interested in ArcGIS, I would recommend you get familiar with the ArcGIS developer site: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/documentation/.  In particular, I recommend the Javascript API documentation.  The are also APIs for Silverlight and Flex but interest in these is dying out in favour of Javascript.

Remember there are other web GIS systems than ArcGIS: e.g. Goolgle Maps API if you only need to work in Web Mercator and have more simple requirements.

As already mentioned, you'll probably find more GIS specific advice on https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It may also be of interest to explore a database such as PostgreSQL if you want to programmatically work with geographical data.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an open ended question but really depends what you want it for? Career wise lots of organisations use Arc Server, but lots of people are going open now and Mapserver, Geoserver and Mapnik are all technologies I would seriously look at.

Learning about the OGC protocols is a good start, i.e WFS, WMS etc.

Open layers and Leaflet and how they can consume data through WMS or WFS, and DB management - i.e. ensuring the data is in good shape and has adequate spatial indexes.

Answer (score 1):

**BASIC**

- Knowledge about web development (Client: HTML, JS, CSS/ Server: Python, NodeJS, etc.): you can learn from the various resources.
- Knowledge about GIS data (2D GIS: Shapefile, GeoJSON, etc. | 3D GIS: CityGML, 3D Tiles, I3S) and where to get them (e.g. [Get data from OpenStreetMap](https://towardsdatascience.com/beginner-guide-to-download-the-openstreetmap-gis-data-24bbbba22a38))
- Software (ESRI Suites, QGIS, AutoCAD, etc.)

**WEB GIS**

- Knowledge to publish your GIS data as a web service: OGC Standards, ArcGIS Rest Service. There are two main types of web map services: Raster (WMS, TMS) or Feature (WFS, GeoJSON, VectorTiles) Example tool: ArcGIS Online, ArcGIS Server, GeoServer.
- Knowledge to build web maps or WebGIS using web services. Example Web map libraries: [ArcGIS JS](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/), [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/), [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/).
- Automation web map builder using ArcGIS Pro or [qgis2web](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/)
- 2.5, 3D Web Visualization: [CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/platform/cesiumjs/), [Deck.gl](https://deck.gl/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first you should start using the internets ... and find even more help here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

if you use Arcmap you will certainly be able to use QGIS, the open source version to manage the same cartographic data you use with Arcmap.
Just install the qgis2web plugin to produce a webgis instantly without spending money on licenses.
A complete guide here http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

I export the map with openlayers and then I added some extensions programmed by Viglino which you can find here https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/
The result is exceptional.

Before qgis2web I did not know programming but the intent to improve my webgis projects started me to research and to understand slowly html code, javascript and css.

I hope you will succeed in your intent.
Greetings.